# User Friendly Exception Handling Libraries for WinForms (.NET)

Tags: .net, winforms, exception

I'm trying to find a nice library for user friendly exception handling for unhandled exceptions.

I found the following one:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/ExceptionHandling.aspx

Is there any other similar projects out there LGPL/Free (or cheap).

I'm looking for features like:

- User friendly crash screen
- Remote Logging with a confirmation button (where use can send error messages over the web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Exception Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309505.aspx) provided by the Microsoft patterns and practices group. I think it is able to do everything you need and more.

Comment: the problem with exception handling application block it's just too over complicated.